# How to solve "no module named" problem for Python when using Environment Modules package?

Tags: python, environment-modules

I am using a software environment loaded with the Environment Modules package (not to be confused with Python modules) using `module load my_env`. Within this environment, I am attempting to run a python script that imports a self-defined Python module using `import my_py_module`. When I tried to run this script, an error is reported saying

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_py_module'

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `my_env` modulefile should update the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to add the location of the `my_py_module`.

```
$ cat /path/to/modulefiles/my_env
#%Module
append-path PYTHONPATH /path/to/my_py_module/location
```

Once such modulefile is loaded, you should be able to run a python script that imports `my_py_module`:

```
$ module use /path/to/modulefiles
$ module load my_env
$ python myscript.py
```